# Is correct to say 'Talk is Talk'?

Tags: grammar

I'm aware of the the phrase 'Talk the talk', but this is my context.

Colleague:

> Why are you applying in another agency? Didn't the boss said that your Item is being processed?

Me:

> Well, he's been saying that for the last 3 years. Talk is talk, but whether they will actually do that is an entirely different matter.

Comment: I'm sure this is OK, but I'm struggling to find references for "X is X" or anything similar. You could compare with the idiom "fun's fun but to hell with nonsense" (which basically means it's good to have fun, but don't take it too far)

Comment: I don't get why I'm being downvoted. It discourages me from posting basic questions. If my questions is dumb then fine. I'm not from the Anglosphere.

Comment: @StuartF thanks. I said it on the spur of the moment. I know it's not the word-for-word idiom (is that even right term?). I just want to make sure I said the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct. You can also use "All talk no action." for the entire sentence.

> Well, he's been saying that for the last 3 years. All talk no action.
>
> Well, he's been saying that for the last 3 years. He(It) is all talk no
> action.
>
> Well, he's been saying that for the last 3 years. He(It) is all talk.
>
> ```
> Or simply
> ```
>
> He is all talk no action.

Comment: The answer does not explain why 'Talk is Talk' is correct, but offers good alternatives.